# Spring Integration - Transformer - Pretty print json string

Tags: spring-integration

If I have a un-formatted JSON as a String object , can I use a spring integration JSON transformer to pretty print it properly? I didn't see any attributes in reference documentation for pretty printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can do it easy enough with Jackson in a POJO transformer - note that you have to convert the JSON to an object and back again...

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Transformer(inputChannel = "foo", outputChannel = "bar")
public String transform(String in) throws Exception {
//  System.out.println(in);
    String out = new String(
            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsBytes(mapper.readValue(in, Object.class)));
//  System.out.println(out);
    return out;
}
```

or...

```
<int:transformer input-channel="foo" output=channel="bar" ref="myJsonPrettyfier" />
```

...if you are using XML.

You could probably even use an `expression`; something like...

```
<int:transformer ...
    expression="new String(@mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsBytes(@mapper.readValue(in, Object.class)))" />
```

Where `mapper` is a `<bean/>` for the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: In my case it's already a String object returned as a Clob from the database so what you have is perfect.